# How do I detect in jQuery (AJAX) when a drop down item is selected on my HTML/PHP page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

How do I detect in jQuery (AJAX) when a drop down item is selected on my HTML page so I can refresh the page? Here is the code for my drop down:

```
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="test1">test1</option>
  <option value="test2">test2</option>
</select>
```

And here is code I have been using to detect a click... how can I get it to detect a change in my drop down?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    // This is our actual script
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#dropdown').click(function(){

                $.ajax({

                    location.reload();

                });

            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

And also, bonus question, right before `location.reload();` how can I set a `$_SESSION` variable in PHP of the select drop down value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the select is changed, reload the page with a querystring with the selected value

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dropdown').on('change', function() {
        window.location.href = window.location.href + '?value=' + this.value;
    });
});
```

it's a simplified example. you'll probably need some parsing for changing the querystring multiple times.

Then catch in PHP and set the $_SESSION etc.

```
$_SESSION['value'] = $_GET['value']
```

Comment: Is there no better way? I'd rather not use query strings if I don't have to.

Comment: There are many other ways, such as ajax, but wether or not they are better is up to you I guess. I don't particularly care for doing ajax requests just to reload the page, it sort of defeats the purpose of ajax. Then there's using a hidden form with a POST method, and submitting that with the value, that would both reload the page and pass the value without an ajax call.

Comment: I ended up going with using a cookie and then doing a refresh. Thanks for the tips though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `$(selector).change()` in staed of `$(selector).click()`

```
 $('#dropdown').change(function(){
        //your code goes here          
 });
```

Comment: What I was going to say

Answer (score 1):

Think you're looking for `.change()` [(Documentation)](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Answer (score 1):

with .change

```
$("#elementID").change(function() {
    alert($("#elementID").val());
}
```